# How to make indicator applet work on AWN?

Tags: awn

Unfortunately Avant Window Navigator's indicator applet doesn't work in 11.10. Is there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is addressed in https://bugs.launchpad.net/awn-extras/+bug/871253. Some users indicate that installing the GTK2 indicator versions (indicator-session-gtk2, indicator-sound-gtk2 ...) makes at least some of the indicators visible.